# Is it important for my company to have a github account to attract good employees?

Tags: hiring

Was listening to a Software Engineering Daily podcast. And I've myself seen a pattern of good companies with a github account and some contribution to open-source.

So, is it a mandate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it important for my company to have a github account to attract good employees?

That really depends on your company culture and mission. If your company is active in open source, or publishes open-source code, then it may make sense.

If your only goal in having a company GitHub account is to attract candidates, then your account contributions will likely stagnate, which will have the opposite effect of discouraging candidates.

GitHub is a tool like anything else, and should be used for its primary purpose of sharing knowledge.

> So, is it a mandate?

Certainly not -- there are plenty of good software companies that do not (or cannot for proprietary reasons) have GitHub accounts, and still manage to be successful in attracting candidates.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is it a mandate?

**No, its not a mandate**.  What a company uses for software version control **alone** cannot determine whether or not a company would be good to work for.  *TFS, subversion, and BitBucket* are also solid solutions.

While the ole Visual Source Safe is way past its prime, you would be amazed how many mid to large size companies still use it.

Comment: If it ain't broke don't fix it! That's why mainframes still exist.